# How do I set the background row color of emails list view in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Previously I used Thunderbird, It has an option to write a custom css for the email list view.

I changed the css so that I am able to set different background colors in the email list view pane.

This way I easily grouped related emails, for eg, red background colored emails are from my boss, green are from clients etc...

So when I scroll the email list view pane of hundreds of emails, it is easy to find the mail just by scanning the colors.

Now company has changed the email client to outlook 2010, I know it is possible to set the foreground color of emails(font color) in the email list view pane using conditional formatting. but I wanted to change the background color of the entire row. Is it possible in Outlook?

Comment: Hi, could you please share such css for Thunderbird?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with the built in tools in Outlook (although maybe a clever VBA script can do it.

Other than changing the font, you can also set the category but this doesn't color in the row (although it does make it filterable by colour which may be a work around).

However, you can change the background color but it changes it for all (although I don't think this is what you want, I'll include the instructions):

- Click the File tab.
- Click Options.
- Under User Interface options, in the Color scheme list, click Blue, Silver, or Black.

You can't assign a stationery for incoming email either which would have solved it. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks @Dave, As you have explained, now I know It is not possible to achieve what I want, but do you know by any chance an add-on available for this?

Comment: Not that I know of - I have looked for this in the past but that was a year or 2 ago - it is possible there is something new but after a quick search for you now, I can find nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use [Conditional Formatting](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2012/05/10/conditional-formatting-highlight-your-most-important-mails.aspx). It is the closest I have been able to get to the way Thunderbird shows Tags/Categories. You can add a new condition and click on the "More Choices" tab to add specific categories, then set the font color for that particular category.